# How to reset db in Django? I get a command 'reset' not found error

Tags: python, database, django, reset

Following this Django by Example tutotrial here: http://lightbird.net/dbe/todo_list.html

The tutorial says:

> "This changes our table layout and we’ll have to ask Django to reset
>   and recreate tables:
>
> `manage.py reset todo; manage.py syncdb`"

though, when I run `manage.py reset todo`, I get the error:

```
$ python manage.py reset todo                                       
- Unknown command: 'reset'
```

Is this because I am using sqlite3 and not postgresql?

**Can somebody tell me what the command is to reset the database?**

The command: `python manage.py sqlclear todo` returns the error:

```
$ python manage.py sqlclear todo    
CommandError: App with label todo could not be found.    
Are you sure your INSTALLED_APPS setting is correct?
```

So I added 'todo' to my INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py, and ran `python manage.py sqlclear todo` again, resulting in this error:

```
$ python manage.py sqlclear todo                                      
- NameError: name 'admin' is not defined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to clear a database from the CLI with manage.py in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485106/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-clear-a-database-from-the-cli-with-manage-py-in-djang)

Answer (score 189, accepted):

`reset` has been replaced by `flush` with Django 1.5, see:

```
python manage.py help flush
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work on individual apps like manage.py reset <appname> did. It results in an error: CommandError: Command doesn't accept any arguments

Comment: Luckily, [someone ported it back](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-reset) to 1.5 :)

Comment: thanks, good to know, recent (last modified 6 months ago) public django documentation about fixtures still (2019-07-11) talks about 'reset': https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Fixtures

Answer (score 42):

It looks like the 'flush' answer will work for some, but not all cases.  I needed not just to flush the values in the database, but to recreate the tables properly.  I'm not using migrations yet (early days) so I really needed to drop all the tables.

Two ways I've found to drop all tables, both require something other than core django.

If you're on Heroku, drop all the tables with pg:reset:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL
heroku run python manage.py syncdb
```

If you can install Django Extensions, it has a way to do a complete reset:

```
python ./manage.py reset_db --router=default
```

Comment: @jonalv, you have to install [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) first.

Comment: Also, you need to have it included under `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.

Answer (score 28):

Similar to LisaD's answer, [Django Extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has a great reset_db command that totally drops everything, instead of just truncating the tables like "flush" does.

`python ./manage.py reset_db`

Merely flushing the tables wasn't fixing a persistent error that occurred when I was deleting objects. Doing a reset_db fixed the problem.

Comment: This was what I was looking for, but I didn't have to provide a `--router` argument, maybe that's optional now, five years later? :)

Answer (score 25):

if you are using Django 2.0
Then

```
python manage.py flush
```

will work

Answer (score 24):

If you want to clean the whole database, you can use:

```bash
python manage.py flush
```

If you want to clean the database table of a Django app, you can use:

```bash
python manage.py migrate <app-name> zero
```

Comment: Although the question is old, this should be the accepted answer. There's no need for django-extensions when migrate zero works fine.

Answer (score 13):

With django 1.11, simply delete all migration files from the `migrations` folder of each application (all files except `__init__.py`). Then

1. Manually drop database.
2. Manually create database.
3. Run `python3 manage.py makemigrations`.
4. Run `python3 manage.py migrate`.

And voilla, your database has been completely reset.

Comment: if using sqlite, no need to manually create the database, `python3 manage.py makemigrations` and  `python3 manage.py migrate` will take care of that, at least in django 2.0

Answer (score 6):

```
python manage.py flush
```

deleted old db contents,

Don't forget to create new superuser:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Answer (score 4):

For me this solved the problem.

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL

heroku run bash
>> Inside heroku bash
cd app_name && rm -rf migrations && cd ..
./manage.py makemigrations app_name
./manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a follow up to [@LisaD's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971577/lisad) answer.
As of 2016 (`Django 1.9`), you need to type:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

This will give you a fresh new database within Heroku.

Answer (score 3):

1. Just manually delete you database. Ensure you create backup first (in my case **db.sqlite3** is my database)
2. Run this command `manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 0):

I use `python manage.py flush` on django 4.1 with postreSQL