# How to reset the database for a particular app in Django 1.5

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.5

What I want is the functionality

```
python manage.py reset myapp
```

What is the equivalent in django 1.5 ?  I am using this in development environmenti.e. sqlite 
(I dont want flush. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use [django_reset](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-reset) package which ports `reset` back in django 1.5:

> This is a port of Django's reset management command that was shipped
>   with Django 1.4.x and earlier. Django 1.5 removed this command.
>
> There might be good reasons not to further maintain it in the Django
>   core, however it was always quite useful during prototyping a new
>   Django based project. Thats why I decided to bring it to Django 1.5
>   and higher with this app.

Answer (score 1):

[Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454008/how-to-reset-db-in-django-i-get-a-command-reset-not-found-error). By the way, try to use [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It allows migrations. It should help to aviod using "reset".