# Can not find "python manage.py reset" command parameters in django1.6

Tags: reset, django-1.6

```
$python manage.py reset 
Unknown command: 'reset'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

In django 1.6 whether to cancel this command parameters yet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset db in Django? I get a command 'reset' not found error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454008/how-to-reset-db-in-django-i-get-a-command-reset-not-found-error)

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me:

```
./manage.py sqlclear AppName | ./manage.py dbshell
```

Found [here](http://www.masnun.com/2013/08/13/django-flush-clear-database.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Django 1.6 and the previous answer didn't work for me. I've been seeking for a way to easily update my database tables, and the best way I've found 'till now is to use *migrations* of South.

1- Install south via pip `pip install south`.
2- Add `south` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.
3- Then run `python manage.py convert_to_south Appname`.
4- And finally run `python manage.py migrate Appname`.

You'll do the three first steps only once, then all you have to do ti update your changes is step 4.